# Getting around "X-Frame-Options" content="deny" for facebook tab page

Tags: facebook, tabs

Ok, so our facebook tab page was working, but now it goes to a blank page. After some investigating I found this in the facebook header, "X-Frame-Options" content="deny" meta tag.

I haven't found any clear way around this. Any ideas? Again, the app page was initially working.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, so our facebook tab page was working, but now it goes to a blank page. After some investigating I found this in the facebook header, "X-Frame-Options" content="deny" meta tag.

If your browser refuses to display *your* page inside of an iframe, then it is *your* server sending this header, not Facebook.

> I haven't found any clear way around this. Any ideas? Again, the app page was initially working.

Talk to your server admin; it looks like he might have changed something concerning the default headers the server puts into the response.